# Swift. How to get generic type from extension?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums, extension-methods

I'm trying to write extension to generic type, but for some reasons in is not working.

I've generic enum:

```
public enum ResponseResult<Result, Error> {

    case Success(result: Result)
    case Failure(error: Error?)
}
```

I want to write some extension to this enum and, for example create another generic class with enum generic params:

```
    extension ResponseResult {

        var response: Response<T> {
            return Response(value: self.value)
        }
    }
```

T - is '`Result`' generic parameter from `ResponseResult` class.
But I don't understand how can i fetch generic parameter in extension.

Comment: It's not clear what you need `T` for, why is it there?

Comment: @Pascal is is generic parameter for Response class. I'm trying to write simple code example not to put all amount of code

Comment: So you just want to use the `Result` generic parameter from the `ResponseResult` enum in the extension? Have you tried just typing `Result` instead of `T`? The generic parameters from the original declaration should be available in the extension.

Comment: Aha. Yes, then it's clear, like others have already replied, you mean `Result`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the parameters from the enum values, you can use `switch-case`:

```
switch response {
case .Success(let result):
    print("Success: \(result)")
case .Failure(let error):
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

If you're inside an extension, simply replace `response` with `self`.

In your specific scenario, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
extension ResponseResult {

    var response: Response<Result>? {
        switch self {
            case .Success(let result):
                return Response(value: result)
            case .Failure: // Ignore error parameter
                return .None
        }
    }
}
```

That pattern is very similar (exactly the same) to what [Alamore](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) uses for error handling. You can see their code and documentation for more samples.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't thought about such an easy way=)